# Cannot access network resources once connected to VPN

Tags: vpn, pptp, watchguard

To begin, it's important this excerpt is read and understood before anything is suggested:

**The VPN configuration has been untouched, as I'm the only admin user, and also the firewall itself has been powered up for over a year. This did work up until last week for several remote users including myself. Much as I hate and disbelieve this statement "it's done it itself" is the best explanation I have**

We have a Watchguard firewall that controls our VPN, so any incoming VPN connections are authenticated by the Watchguard. We can still "log on" to the VPN just fine without error. However, once on the network, we cannot access or ping any resources including Windows servers and Macs.

We have several remote users who all reported a problem accessing network resources at a similar time. This was in the middle of a business day whilst all operations were up and running and in use locally by over 20 people. Since this time and leading up to it, no resources were altered or restarted, including the Watchguard, as I said it's uptime is over a year.

We can connect onto the VPN fine, but cannot ping either IP's or hostnames of any network resources.

If anyone can provide any pointers on where to start looking that would be great. It's unlikely to require much change in configuration as it's been a working VPN with access to all network resources for several employees for a couple of years now, this is the first problem which appears to have arrived out of nowhere.

Cheers

Comment: Well, just because its running without any problem for a year, it doesn't guarantee that things can't go wrong with it. Lots of things can happen. Is it possible that your firewall got some firmware/software upgrade automatically? The first thing you should do, is to log into the firewall and check the log files if there is some hints in vpn or firewall logs or system logs. There can be also hardware problem, may be disk full, memory usage full or similar things. Check the firewall first, that would be my suggestion.

Comment: What's the make and model of your WG appliance? Is it XTM 510 on a certain firmware? In any case, since it's been up for over a year, it can get fragmented memory, etc. just like any other device and may need a reboot. I'd definitely check the logs for any indicator of issue, ensure you have your configurations backed up just in case, and then perhaps reboot the device and have somone on standby to test while you're physically at the device. There could perhaps be some beug with your model and firmware versions that's pathced as well I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just because its running without any problem for a year, it doesn't guarantee that things can't go wrong with it. Lots of things can happen. Is it possible that your firewall got some firmware/software upgrade automatically?

The first thing you should do, is to log into the firewall and check the log files if there is some hints in vpn or firewall logs or system logs. There can be also hardware problem, may be disk full, memory usage full or similar things. Check the firewall first, that would be my suggestion.